# gtag sending two events for a single call

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

Referencing https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/api I am calling `gtag('event', 'sign_up')` when a sign up happens. This results in a single network call being made which for some reason clearly contains two events in the payload. One event has an "engagment time" of 1 millisecond whereas the other has an engagement time value of many seconds -- it looks like it is roughly the period of time since when the previous event was triggered?

This results in two `sign_up` events being recorded by Google Analytics. I am only using Google Analytics and `gtag`, not GTM or anything else.

How can I make the `gtag` call send just one event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was because I had made a custom event in GA for the `sign_up` event which I thought was necessary. Just needed to delete that custom event and everything worked as expected.

Comment: I did something similar when testing custom events. Could not work out where the event was coming from. Thanks for sharing the solution.